# How do I access individual elements in $FirebaseArray without waiting for it to $loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I request some data from Firebase using [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) like below.

`$rootScope.userTags = $firebase($fbCurrent.child('tags')).$asArray();`

On logging this data in following ways I get the outputs as in the image below. So,

```
console.log($rootScope.userTags);
console.log($rootScope.userTags[0]);
$rootScope.userTags.$loaded().then(function () {
  console.log($rootScope.userTags[0]);
});
```

[image]

In first log statement you can notice an `$FirebaseArray` object with five elements. In second log statement when I try to access one of the elements, I get `undefined` although you can clearly see those elements in the un`$loaded` array. Now in the last log statement, calling `$loaded` lets me access those elements without any issues.

Why does it behave this way? And is there a way I can access those elements, since those are already there, without calling `$loaded` on the array?

Comment: Generally, just set up a directive like `ng-repeat` to print the content in your view, drop the object in $scope, and let Angular worry about when it loads. This is kind of the point of the synchronized objects and bindings. If you want to manipulate the data in your controller, which you probably should not be doing, then you need to wait for it to load. If you are attempting to transform data from the server, utilize $extendFactory as explained in the docs and again, don't worry about when it loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$asArray()` or `$asObject()` methods are asynchronous actions. The data has to be downloaded from Firebase before it can be accessed. This is just the nature of asynchronous data and not anything specific to Firebase.

The way we handle this issue of asynchrony is through the `$loaded` promise.

It seems though the real issue here ensuring data is loaded upon instantiation of the controller. You can solve this be resolving the data in the router.

Resolve require a promise to be returned. When the user routes to that page, Angular will not load the page until the promise has been resolved. The data resolved from the promise will injected into the controller.

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

      .when('/resolve', {
        templateUrl: 'resolve.html',
        controller: 'ResolveCtrl',

        resolve: {
          // data will be injected into the ResolveCtrl
          data: function($firebase) {
           // resolve requires us to return a promise
           return $firebase(new Firebase('your-firebase')).$asArray().$loaded();
          }
        }

      })
  }
])
```

Now that we are resolving the data in the route we can access it in our controller.

```
.controller('ResolveCtrl', function($scope, data) {

  $scope.userTags = data;
  $scope.userTags[0]; // data has been resolved from the promise

});
```

Comment: A great answer to the specific question, but I feel it's important to point out that in many cases where one would even care if data is loaded, it's because they are wasting effort and energy modifying data in the controller instead of using $extendFactory or just putting the data into $scope and letting the view take care of rendering.